# Why doesn't babel-standalone@6 work in Firefox 20?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, babeljs

I wrote the some code and when opened the page in browser (Firefox 20.0), it showed following error in console:

JS: https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js

TypeError: e.forEach is not a function @ https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js:8

**CODE:**

```
<script type="text/babel">
   let input = [1, 2, 3];
   console.log(typeof input);
</script>
```

I observed that using "**let**" or "**var**" doesn't make a difference. It is crashing even before reaching those lines. Why is it so? Am I missing something?

PS: Although I can use NPM and browserify to use babel but i just want to test it using this script.

Comment: can you put it in fiddle or code pen?

Comment: Are you able to update your browser? Firefox 20 is extremely old

Comment: I would, but isn't this is why we use Babel standalone to support new syntax and services of latest JS? Or even Babel has compatibility issues with Browser versions? Like it would work after a specific version? @loganfsmyth I tried to find about these queries online but didn't find anything related to Babel standalone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be because the version of Firefox you're using is not supported by Lodash, which Babel depends on https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2924

Generally babel-standalone targets standard ES5 environments, but this appears to be a case that we can't address since it is in one of our dependencies.

Comment: Hi thank you. " but this appears to be a case that we can't address since it is in one of our dependencies." What does it mean? Could you please tell a bit more? And "targets ES5" => Does it mean it compiles modern JS to ES5 and browser must support ES5 for it to work?

Comment: There's two different questions of "support". What babel-standalone will run on, and what the code it outputs will run on. babel-standalone basically aims for ES5 environments. How it compiles code depends entirely on how it is configured and what the user's code was doing originally. babel-standalone is a build tool, it isn't meant to be run client-side in production, that just happens to be a nice way to prototype out things, hence support for FF 20 is not important.

Comment: Okay. Now I guess it doesn't work in FF 20 because browser may not support some of features of ES5 (?). I searched more about this and found another behaviour. I included this link https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.26.0/polyfill.min.js  just before babel-standalone, and Lo! Everything is working! Can you please tell something about that? (I assume that polyfill contains features that browsers don't support, to support them).

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox 20 because that version has a non-standard implementation of an ES6 feature. Lodash is detecting that the ES6 feature is available even though it isn't actually. By adding that polyfill first, you're fixing that, so that babel-standalone will work properly. That's a good solution :)

Comment: But by using babel / polyfill we're "converting ES6 to ES5", so what it has to do with FF 20's not standard implementation of *ES6* ? That's confusing.

Comment: Shouldn't it be  "not standard implementation of *ES5* "?

Comment: No, Lodash uses ES6 features when it detects they exist, and in this case Firefox 20 has a incorrect ES6 feature and Lodash is trying to use it anyway. Generally browsers like Firefox and Chrome are considered "evergreen" because they auto-update, so libraries do not attempt to support extremely old versions of them.

Comment: Okay. But by this logic, if FF 20 has correct implementation of ES6, this babel-standalone would work in newer browsers even without that polyfill script (Yes, it works, I tried :)) ? And now the question arises: If we use newer browsers to support babel, WHY DO WE EVEN NEED babel if we could use newer browsers? Isn't that contradiction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164452/discussion-between-loganfsmyth-and-rahul).

Comment: @loganfsmyth a question about compilation: You wrote " babel-standalone basically aims for ES5 environments". Is it true even if it is used babel using node babelify and creating budle.js (as give in setup guides) using Browserify and use it in a Chrome 64? Does it ALWAYS compile the ECMA 2015 code to ES5?

Comment: That comment was in reference to babel-standalone _itself_ running, not what the code it outputs will run on. What the code it outputs does entirely depends on how what plugins and presets you enable in Babel, just like the non-standalone version of Babel.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I sent you final message on Chat can you please reply that?